# How do you read the git section in the powerlevel10k prompt?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

[image]

I am having a hard time understanding the yellow part of the prompt (git).

What do the `!5 ?7` indicate?

Comment: Duplicate. See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62084089/1095235

Answer (score 4):

Answer [here](https://github.com/romkatv/gitstatus)

`!5` = 5 unstaged changes

`?7` = 7 untracked files

[image]