# All branch names in command line are followed by *2

Tags: git, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have a repository where all my branches suddenly are followed by `*2` in the terminal.

[image: command line]

We recently switched from Github to Gitlab, which meant dealing with multiple origins at some point. I was sure this would be the cause of the issue seeing how this is the only project I used multiple origins in while also beeing the only project showing `*2`. Sure enough, the project had multiple origins. I removed the old one, but the `*2` is still showing. I tried googling and asking chatGPT, but I am coming up short.

Here´s the output of `git remote -v` after deleting the other origin, which is correct according to the output I get from my other git projects.

[image: output from listing origins]

Other things I tried:

- Restarting editor & terminal
- Switching branches back and forth
- reconfiguring `p10k` (just in case)
- looked through `.git/config`

Comment: related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62072056/characters-1-and-2-in-command-prompt

Answer (score 2):

The number is the amount of stashes I currently have. It is a symbol given by the Powerlevel10k zsh plugin. Here is more information about [the git symbols shown by p10k](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/blob/master/README.md#what-do-different-symbols-in-git-status-mean).

So I found the answer and it was unrelated to amount of origins. It was simply a misunderstanding happening in the midst of defaulting and reconfiguring p10k for my zsh terminal.

I used this command twice in order to remove the symbol from my command line:

```
git stash drop
```

Comment: For completeness and in general, it would be better to use `git stash list` and `git stash show` to examine whatever stashes are found before deciding to delete them.